# How does mysql execute a query using an index plus a filter

Tags: mysql, sql, theory

Given a table with columns `a`, `b` and `c`. Assume an **index** is created on columns `a` and `b`, how will MYSQL execute a query with a `WHERE` clause using criteria `a`, `b` and `c`.

**Additional notes:** Will MYSQL use an Index Range Scan in this scenario or do a full table scan for column `c`?

Comment: why not use explain to see what MySQL makes?

Comment: Why do you mention index range scan?  I see no mention of any ranges of values?  Is this a question from a test or something?  Do you have any guesses?

Comment: My guess (i.e.) hope is that MYSQL uses the index scan (a, b) and then filters the results with criteria of (c).

Comment: EXPLAIN does show me that index (a,b) will be used but I'm not sure if this means that a full row scan is not needed for (c) and that it will use the index results for its criteria

Comment: It will use the index results, yes

Comment: why not have a index for (a,b,c) if that is a query that runs regurlarly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses the index on `(a, b)` to reduce the *examined rows* to the set matching your conditions on those two columns.

Then that set of examined rows are evaluated one by one for the other condition on column `c`. It doesn't do a full table scan, but it does evaluate all of the examined rows.

You can get an estimate of the examined row count from the `rows` field of the EXPLAIN report.